# cakephp OR condition not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table of Events which belongsTo a Meeting. Events hasAndBelongsToMany Groups, Segments, Areas, and Regions. Currently the page displays all events which have at least 1 group, segment, area, and region they are linked to which the user is also linked to. I added a field to the events table, filtered_by_area, which checks whether the Event should only display to certain Areas/Regions or to everyone. I need to change the find so that the events that display are either those where filtered_by_area is 0, or if the event is linked to the same areas/regions as the user. But I can't seem to make it show the unfiltered event. Here is my code:

```
$conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Meeting.id' => $id,
                array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array("Event.filtered_by_area" => 0),
                    array("AreasEvent.area_id IN ('$areas')",
                          "EventsRegion.region_id IN ('$regions')")
                ))
            ),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'events',
                    'alias' => 'Event',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Meeting.id = Event.meeting_id'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'areas_events',
                    'alias' => 'AreasEvent',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Event.id = AreasEvent.event_id',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'areas',
                    'alias' => 'Area',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Area.id = AreasEvent.area_id',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'events_regions',
                    'alias' => 'EventsRegion',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Event.id = EventsRegion.event_id',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'regions',
                    'alias' => 'Region',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Region.id = EventsRegion.region_id',
                    )
                )
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Event.Segment',
                'Event.Asset' => array(
                    'Image',
                    'Document',
                    'VimeoVideo',
                    'Link'
                ),
                'Event.Group' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Group.name' => $this->group_name
                    )
                ),
                'Event.Area' => array(),
                'Event.Region' => array()
            )
        );

        if (!$this->Meeting->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid meeting'));
        }

        $conditions['contain']['Event.Segment'] = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Segment.id' => $segments
            )
        );

        $conditions['contain']['Event.Area'] = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Area.id' => $areas
            )
        );

        $conditions['contain']['Event.Region'] = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Region.id' => $regions
            )
        );

        if (isset($dates[$day])) {
            $conditions['contain']['Event'] = array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'date_format(Event.start, "%Y-%m-%d")' => $dates[$day]
                ),
                'order' => 'Event.start asc'
            );
        }
        $meeting = $this->Meeting->find('first', $conditions);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

this here :

> 'OR' => array(
>                       array("Event.filtered_by_area" => 0),
>                       array("AreasEvent.area_id IN ('$areas')",
>                             "EventsRegion.region_id IN ('$regions')")
>                   ))

remove this, and change to this way :

'contain'=>array(
 'Model'=>array('condition'=>$condition)
)

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. I added the following to the 'contain' array :

    'contain' => array(
        'Event' => array(
     'condition' => array(
            'Event.filtered_by_asset' => 0)),

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
array(
    'OR' => array(
        array("Event.filtered_by_area" => 0),
        array("AreasEvent.area_id IN ('$areas')",
              "EventsRegion.region_id IN ('$regions')")
    ))
)
```

Remove the array that wraps the 'OR'. It would be like this:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Meeting.id' => $id,
    'OR' => array(
        "Event.filtered_by_area" => 0,
        'AND' => array(
            "AreasEvent.area_id" => $areas,
            "EventsRegion.region_id" => $regions
        )
    ))
)
```

**EDIT:** Corrected the `IN` clause. If `$areas` and `$regions` are array, Cake will do automatically a `IN` statement on the query

**EDIT 2:** Corrected arrays inside `OR`

**EDIT 3:** Third edit =_= added `AND`

Comment: Check my edited answer. Assuming that `$areas` and `$regions` are array, of course

Comment: No go. Also, wouldn't that be incorrect? It looks like its saying

        "Event.filtered_by_area" => 0
         OR
        "AreasEvent.area_id" => $areas
         OR
        "EventsRegion.region_id" => $regions

Which would be incorrect. I want to say

        (Event.filtered_by_area" => 0)
         OR
        ("AreasEvent.area_id" => $areas AND
        "EventsRegion.region_id" => $regions)

Comment: Then you have to tell explicitely that after an `OR` you want an `AND` statement, or Cake won't recognize it. So, check (again =_=) the edit please.

Comment: Still nothing. I'm thinking it has something to do with the joins but I'm just grasping at straws.

Comment: Then please post the query that Cake generates

Comment: Turns out there was code in the View that removed all Events which had no Areas/Regions. What's more, the View code is the only thing doing the filtering, the query in the Controller isn't working properly. I just checked for the filtered_by_area attribute in the View. I know its not proper MVC but I gotta get it done. Thanks for all your help.